# PEP 8 and deferred import

Tags: python, pep8

I am working on a large Python program which makes use of a multitude of modules depending on command-line options, in particular, `numpy`.  We have recently found a need to run this on a small embedded module which precludes the use of numpy.  From our perspective, this is easy enough (just don't use the problematic command line options.)

However, following [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), our `import numpy` is at the beginning of each module that might need it, and the program will crash due to `numpy` not being installed.  The straightforward solution is to move `import numpy` from the top of the file to the functions that need it.  The question is,  "How bad is this"?

(An alternative solution is to wrap `import numpy` in a `try .. except`.  Is this better?)

Comment: Since it is an opinion, I would go for `try....except` where-ever I use the optional module. This would be useful if you wrap the information about the use case of optional module i.e `numpy` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a best practice pattern to check if a module is installed and make code branch depending on it.

```
# GOOD
import pkg_resources

try:
    pkg_resources.get_distribution('numpy')
except pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound:
    HAS_NUMPY = False
else:
    HAS_NUMPY = True
    # You can also import numpy here unless you want to import it inside the function
```

Do this in every module imports having soft dependency to numpy. [More information in Plone CMS coding conventions](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone.api/docs/contribute/conventions.html).

Comment: Should I worry about circular imports when importing libraries? (Very interesting! +1)

Comment: That's why we are not catching `ImportError` which is bad practice because of this and couple of other pitfalls like native dependencies blowing up

Comment: But can it blow up in most cases? I can understand this could happen when importing things from within your own module... but not when importing numpy (or other external libraries).

Comment: For example when importing Python Imaging Library if your native codecs are broken you will never get a clue about the actual root cause - naive implementation does only print("Install PIL")

Comment: Hmmm. In that specific case, I think it's a question of responsibility: if you can't do the import but can still carry on with the rest of the program (e.g. in vanilla python rather than PIL/numpy) should you? Or should you complain you have a bad installation/version of PIL/numpy, and exit. It's not obvious to me which is preferable...

Comment: The plone example is for importing for an internal module, so I'm not sure it's even clear in their style guide.

Comment: It will check if the package exists and then fail with the proper error when you try to import numpy and it imports are broken

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa - can I do something akin to `from numpy import np` if I go the `pkg_resources.get_distribution` route?  (I ended up doing something akin to what Andy suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33796601/3061818, but I see that this may be problematic.)

Comment: Checking if certain package is installed and importing that package are two separate problems. 1) First check if package is available 2) Then feel free to import any module from the package it if the package is installed - no need to check for ImportError

Answer (score 1):

Another idiom which I've seen is to import the module as None if unavailable:

```
try:
    import numpy as np
except ImportError:
    np = None
```

*Or, [as in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33789037/1240268), you can use the `pkg_resources.get_distribution` above, rather than try/except (see [the blog post](http://do3.cc/blog/2010/08/20/do-not-catch-import-errors,-use-pkg_resources/) linked to from the [plone docs](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone.api/docs/contribute/conventions.html#about-imports)).*

In that way, before using numpy you can hide numpy's use in an if block:

```
if np:
     # do something with numpy
else:
     # do something in vanilla python
```

---

The *key* is to ensure your CI tests have both environments - with and without numpy (and if you are testing coverage this should count both block as covered).